# Need to connect a small speaker (should have functional volume) and power it with raspberrypi.

Tags: pi-3

I just started using Raspberry pi. For the project I am working I have and to put a small speaker inside a case and it should not have a battery. I have tried small speaker that are just powered by AUX and their sound is really really low. Can anyone suggest me any small speaker model that can be powered by USB of the raspberry and get the output from the 3.5 mm output of Raspberry. Need desperate help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many USB powered speakers out there. [A quick Newegg search](https://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=usb%20powered%20speakers&Submit=ENE) will reveal them, and you should probably pick from there to find a speaker that best fits your needs from there.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it already. I am looking for something a bit smaller than 
https://www.newegg.com/global/au/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA7256ME5830&cm_re=usb_powered_speakers-_-19S-00U8-00001-_-Product
It has to sit inside a shell with a limited space.

Comment: If you need to slim it down a bit, you could always remove the casing for the speakers if you only need a little bit smaller of a unit.